# Validate condition using PHP and AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, dynamic

***Ignore all struck text***.

The struggle is real for this one. In an `index.php` file with mostly HTML code I have multiple `<span>` elements acting as buttons with `class="delete_this"`:

```
<ul id="products">
    <li class="product">
        <!-- more code -->
        <div class="select-delete">
            <span class="delete-product delete_this" title="Delete"></span>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="product">
        <!-- more code -->
        <div class="select-delete">
            <span class="delete-product delete_this" title="Delete"></span>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="product">
        <!-- more code -->
        <div class="select-delete">
            <span class="delete-product delete_this" title="Delete"></span>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

When any `<span>` element (*technically any*) with `class="delete_this"` is clicked, a jQuery AJAX request is made:

```
// The exact following line is a simple on click function, it's a little different
// than the usual since I'm loading .delete_this also dynamically. It runs when you click
// on any element *.delete_this
$("#products").on("click", ".delete_this", function(event) {
    var $count = $("#products > li").length;
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "validate_existence.php",
        // The following sends some data to the validate_existence.php file
        data: {"quantity_of_products": $count},
```

```
        success:function(html) {
            if (html == "true") {
                // condition met
            } else {
                // condition not met
            }
        }
```

```
    });
});
```

So, the user clicks on `<span class="delete_this">`, then: (1) a variable is defined and (2) the AJAX is requested, sending as data the value of that variable.

Now, in `validate_existence.php` I want a conditional statement to be made, using `if () {}`. The criteria to be tested is if the variable `$count` sent in the AJAX request is equal to 1:

```
<?php

if ( $_POST['quantity_of_products'] = 1 ) {  // Edit: thanks everyone for saying to use two equal symbols
    // Run code if criteria is met
} else {
    // Run code if criteria is not met
}

?>
```

<s>The problem is the code in `// condition not met` inside index.php is **always run**, even if the criteria wasn't met (A.K.A. `$_POST['quantity_of_products'] /= 1`).</s>

I'm most likely missing something in the `validate_existence.php` file<s>, or using `function(html)` incorrectly in `index.php`</s>.

Comment: You can debug your ajax using FireBug

Comment: $_POST['quantity_of_products'] = 1 is assigning value to the $_POST['quantity_of_products']  variable you have to use ==

Comment: first print the `print_r($_POST);` variable in you `validate_existence.php` file and check what you get?

Comment: You should replace `if ( $_POST['quantity_of_products'] = 1 )` with `if ( $_POST['quantity_of_products'] == 1 )`

Comment: OK people thank you all for the ridiculous mistake I made using a single equal sing. I changed it but still nothing. I'll add some of the HTML.

Comment: @chris85 the conditional function isn't run (JS in index.php).

Comment: The code in `// condition not met` is **always run**, even if the criteria wasn't met (A.K.A. `$_POST['quantity_of_products'] /= 1`).

Comment: You probably have whitespace. Try `if (html.trim() == "true") {`

Comment: your returning boolen value so don't check as string in ajax success function . do like this if (html == true) {
               alert("yes");
            } else {
              alert("not");
            }

Comment: @Anant added the HTML code inside index.php.

Comment: @alej27 soo no??? I guess I'll just leave this here, `If a file is pure PHP code, it is preferable to omit the PHP closing tag at the end of the file. This prevents accidental whitespace or new lines being added after the PHP closing tag, which may cause unwanted effects because PHP will start output buffering when there is no intention from the programmer to send any output at that point in the script.`.

Comment: @alej27 this question appears to be abandoned.  Where are you with this issue? All questions on this site deserve resolution.  Can you clarify the issue so that a suitable solution can be provided?  Where is the problem after you fix the typo in the conditional?

Answer (score 3):

Change the following line:

```
if($_POST['quantity_of_products'] = 1)    // This is assignment
```

to

```
if($_POST['quantity_of_products'] == 1)   // This is condition checking
```

Answer (score 2):

`$_POST['quantity_of_products'] = 1` is assigning value to the `$_POST['quantity_of_products']` variable. so you have to use like this `$_POST['quantity_of_products']==1`

```
if($_POST['quantity_of_products'] == 1)
```

Comment: Isn't the response a string? `The success callback function is passed the returned data, which will be an XML root element or a text string depending on the MIME type of the response.`

Comment: able to get the string as response but he returning boolen value so i said like this

Comment: yeah i agree with you @chris85

Comment: `your returning boolen value so don't check as string in ajax success function`, but `html` will be a string, not boolean, no?

Comment: @chris85 Actually, I can delete the `functinon(html)` in `index.php` and simply execute the response in the same `validate_existance.php` file. And yes, I understand if so then I'll have to write the code in PHP and not in jQuery/JS.

Comment: @alej27 Not sure what you mean.. I'm done here though. My comment has gone +20 minutes without being addressed.

Answer (score 0):

I think  best way is use ternary operator:

```
<?php

if ( $_POST['quantity_of_products'] = 1 ) {
    echo true;
} else {
    echo false;
}

?>
```

Replace code with

```
<?php
$test = $_POST['quantity_of_products'] == 1? true: false;
echo $test;
```